# How to disable throwing DotvvmInterruptRequestExecutionException?

Tags: c#, mvvm, dotvvm

I am experimenting with DotVVM framework and sometimes Visual Studio throws a DotvvmInterruptRequestExecutionException.

I know that this exception is used to interrupt execution of the current request to be able to redirect. However, I would like to stop this exception being thrown.

I know that it is possible, I just can't find out how to do it.

Comment: The exception has to be thrown. You can only explain your debugger to not stop on it. In Visual Studio use Exception Settings window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have written a blog post which explains, why the exception is being thrown and how can you set Visual Studio not to break on this exception.

http://www.dotvvm.com/blog/1/Why-I-am-getting-the-DotvvmInterruptRequestExecutionException-